# high current UPS ish design

Tags: arduino, charge, ups, controller

This is my latest attempt to try building a ups ish system for my 3D printer
the printer is custom-designed with 5 meters (no, it's not a typo) on each axis.

we use MKS Gen v1.1 with custom marlin core.

this board can handle 12-24v.

with our calculation, our current draw is 20 to 60 amps when bed and nozzle are heating up.

so a commercial UPS is not affordable.

I came up with the following circuit as our power source.

I could use some tips to optimize it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fORhuR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know it's not pretty

My charge controller is Arduino Mega with the following algorithm:

if the battery voltage drops below 11.5 the relay is connected to charge the battery up to 13 volts then the relay is disconnected.

V1 is a power source with 80 amps capacity.

V2 is 3 car batteries connected in parallel. (to handle the sudden current shock)

There is a backup generator behind V1 which starts if V2 drops below 11.2.

There are other loads on the printer side that are mission-critical and can not be turned off even for 1 second.

P.S: I was thinking about adding a capacitor to smooth out the voltage but I could use a bit of help to calculate its capacity.

P.S2: we are planning to add solar panel as V3 later this year...

P.S3:  I know, I know its idiotic, but we are tight on budget and cannot afford a big UPS we are pretty much out of money and this printer is our income source ...

( it took me around 35 days to build this printer, speed is 3mm/min, it's huge )

Comment: Could you state the question more clearly?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I need some optimization on my circuit to lower any risk, if possible

Comment: Optimization requires to define criteria and constraints. E.g. optimizing for max current with limited cost will give a different result than optimizing for min cost with a minimum required current.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm looking for optimization in terms of clean voltage and clean current with cost in mind to minimize any possible damage to the printer. I'd sleep better if I could keep the voltage on 12v

Comment: And why do you need an UPS? There are plenty of off-the-shelf power supplies for 12..24V. 60A is a high current but not unheard of.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev power in our area is not reliable. and our printer can't resume it's work if it is interrupted

Comment: How long are the outages? Seconds, minutes, hours? Can the printer be put on pause to lower power requirements during an outage? The main thing you want to avoid is an undefined state by power outage that prevents a continuation of printing.

Comment: To expand further, my 3D printer is able to be put on pause and control it's heating elements. Doing this drastically lowers the power requirements to the point that even a modestly sized UPS would work for your use, and thus likely affordable.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev power outages are around 2-4 hours per day. the printer can not be paused as the extruder and other parts are heavy and put a lot of stress on step motors so they must keep working and have power. an uninterruptable power source is our only choice. ( extruder module and all of its connections weight about 25kg ) again it's a big job

Comment: Wow, 25kg is quite a lot. I'd still suggest a pause functionality, with maybe a movement to a resting position during pause to deal with the weight support.

Comment: How is the weight dealt with when the printer is at rest?

Comment: @JarrodChristman Our metallurgy engineer forbid us from pausing the operation as he believes doing so will damage the integrity ( we are not using honeycomb method). when the printer is not working the whole assembly will move to a parking like area. yes, 25kg is heavy and it's a big thing !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96620/discussion-between-jarrod-christman-and-far2005).

Answer (score 1):

A low-noise 80A battery charger should be able to deal with this. It's the same kind of issue that folks confront at trade shows to keep car batteries alive while they're powering all their gizmos on the show floor.

Example: http://soundsgreatusa.com/cascade-aps-90-amp-1200-watts-pro-grade-power-supply-dual-volt-marine-ready/

Another: https://www.powerstream.com/charger-low-noise-high-power.htm

The power supply would connect to an automatic transfer switch, which would be part of the genset or a separate item.

Comment: I already have a big power supply. is the circuit safe?

Comment: The unit I linked is designed specifically to be tied in parallel with batteries to not only charge them but to supply the load as well. I can't say the same thing about your power supply - you seem to have doubts about it given the complex diode-and-relay solution you propose. Looks sketchy to me, plus development time... better to buy the pre-engineered solution I think.

Comment: So this unit has a built-in charge controller? I prefer to be safe than sorry thus the diode solution

Comment: Yes, it has built-in charge control. It would be safer than what you propose assuming your power supply isn't designed to charge lead-acid batteries.

Comment: Ours is a Meanwell with 80 amps capacity and variable voltage, I cranked up the voltage to charge the battery and made my own charge controller

Comment: Lead-acid charging isn't as simple as just feeding 13.5V to the battery. Your solution needs to know how to do a taper / float charge too. More about that here: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_with_a_power_supply

Comment: TBH, I don't want to bother about the battery life, even if the battery lasts for 1 year is good enough. I forgot to mention, I do monitor the battery temp to prevent boiling

Comment: If you're using a deep-cycle or AGM type battery, they get very expensive: $300-400. If you only get 1 year out of the batteries as opposed to 3 years, for 3 batteries your cost of ownership is $900~$1200 per year. The adapters I linked are about $400. Your choice.

Comment: I'm using a car battery, it's like $70. and I'm not depleting it entirely, only like 20 30%.